# Calculate count of type in one column for each date in other column using Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, date, excel-formula

I am trying a macro to give me count of columnA containing type of elements per date in columnB. I need to multiply each type count with certain value(volume calculation) and keep total per type per date in new sheet.

Sample data:

```
Large        12/12/2016  
Large        12/12/2016
Medium       12/12/2016
Medium       12/12/2016
Medium       12/12/2016
Medium       12/12/2016
Medium       12/12/2016
Medium       12/12/2016    
Medium       12/12/2016
Small        12/12/2016
Large        12/12/2016
Extra Large  12/12/2016
Extra Large  12/12/2016
Extra Large  12/12/2016
```

Here is my thought process for algorithm.

1. Loop each row and try to group dates and find count of each date and paste it in new cell and replace if same date is found again.
2. Loop from min date to max date. Fetch all rows for current date and find count of them and place it in new sheet for each date

Is this doable using any of the above? If not can some one help me with new algorithm possible pseudo code. 
Please ignore if you feel naive.

Comment: You can do this with a pivot table and no coding...

Comment: I did not quite understand what you meant. So, do you want to see for example how many Small/medium/large/extra large belongs to each different dates?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pivot table that made with your sample data. Also, I made a video so you can see how to create it. With more data you can see you can do much more stuff. If this is what you were looking for, please hit the checkmark next to this answer to mark it.

File:

http://www.filedropper.com/pivot

Video:

https://www.screencast.com/t/BJBUIJPu76